# NullpointerException while using RealM

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using the RealM Library to store my values in the database.
The problem is that since RealM does not support AutoIncrement i am trying to implement it by my own.

This is my modal class:

```
public class User extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private  int rollno;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }


    public int getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I my main class i have a function named insertValues in which i am inserting the data in the database.

```
 public void insertValues(Realm realm,String name,int rollNo)
    {

        realm.beginTransaction();

        int nextId = (int)(realm.where(User.class).maximumInt("id") + 1); // this line gives me nullpointer error. Please help

        User user = realm.createObject(User.class);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setRollno(rollNo);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

My Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.realm.RealmQuery.maximumInt(RealmQuery.java:1421)
at realmsample.bd.com.realmsample.MainActivity.insertValues(MainActivity.java:105)
at realmsample.bd.com.realmsample.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When you first time add an object in RealM database, your line `realm.where(User.class).maximumInt("id")` will give you NULL values as there is no data added in database. Just keep an if conditoin before getting maximum value form database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1580),
It's fairly similar as your issue,
So as suggested,

> If max related function is called on an empty results query or query's results are all null values, `maximumInt` will throw an exception.

So use [`RealmQuery.max()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#max-java.lang.String-) instead.

Comment: can you tell me an example to do this.. i did not find any example to do this

Comment: Didn't you try `max("id")` as linked documentation above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your code while fetching max value of "id" field. *When you add first object in the database, **maximumInt("id")**  will be NULL*.

So you need to keep an if condition to prevent NPE.

```
int nextId = 1;
if (realm.where(User.class).findAll().size() > 0) {
    nextId  = (int)(realm.where(User.class).maximumInt("id") + 1)
}
```